# What are derived variables in react and how can I use them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What are derived variables in React JS? Can they help clean up my code and improve readab

Comment: Please note, SO is not a wiki..

Answer (score 0):

Derived variables are constant variables that are initialed and dependent on a useState. Why use them? Well, they just have to be defined once, and never refined again. Let’s take a look at this code here. (Ignore all caps at the first line)

```
Function App(){
    Const [name, setName] = useState(“”)
    Const [error, setError] = useState(false)
    UseEffect(()=>setError(name.length>100),[name])
…

}
```

In this code, we are ALWAYS calling a useEffect every time name gets changed. Now that’s fine and all, but what happens when we have a lot of variables we have to keep track of, and we have to update errors in many different places. That can be EXTREMELY frustrating. Luckily, React has derived variables, or variables can update automatically when a useState (or set of useStates) changes. Best thing of all, we DO NOT have to use any additional libraries

Let’s see how this code works with derived variables

```
Function App(){
    Const [name, setName] = useState(“”)
    Const error = name.length>100
…

}
```

That’s it. That’s literally it. Error is now derived by name and on each rerender, error will be updated automatically when a useState is called. If you want to ONLY update error when a specific useState variable changes, you can use `useMemo`’s dependency array.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Keywords like `function` and `const` are case-sensitive. This code wouldn't work.